# How to write a frontend for company-mode that allows the pseudo-tooltip but restricts it further?

Tags: company-mode

I'd like to have a pseudo tooltip available but restrict its appearance more than the default options allow. For example, I might want it to only appear if no input has come for some period of time, or to wait for a tab before appearing. I know how to sleep and how to wait for a tab, but I do not know how to make sure the tooltip appears only under certain circumstances but also always disappears and changes as normal when visible.

For reference, this is some of the relevant code in `company.el`. It takes one of the following arguments: `'show, 'hide, 'update, 'pre-command, or 'post-command.`

```
(defun company-pseudo-tooltip-unless-just-one-frontend (command)
  "`company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend', but not shown for single candidates."
  (unless (and (eq command 'post-command)
               (company--show-inline-p))
    (company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend command)))

(defun company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend (command)
  "`company-mode' frontend similar to a tooltip but based on overlays."
  (cl-case command
    (pre-command (company-pseudo-tooltip-hide-temporarily))
    (post-command
     (unless (when (overlayp company-pseudo-tooltip-overlay)
              (let* ((ov company-pseudo-tooltip-overlay)
                     (old-height (overlay-get ov 'company-height))
                     (new-height (company--pseudo-tooltip-height)))
                (and
                 (>= (* old-height new-height) 0)
                 (>= (abs old-height) (abs new-height))
                 (equal (company-pseudo-tooltip-guard)
                        (overlay-get ov 'company-guard)))))
       ;; Redraw needed.
       (company-pseudo-tooltip-show-at-point (point) (length company-prefix))
       (overlay-put company-pseudo-tooltip-overlay
                    'company-guard (company-pseudo-tooltip-guard)))
     (company-pseudo-tooltip-unhide))
    (hide (company-pseudo-tooltip-hide)
          (setq company-tooltip-offset 0))
    (update (when (overlayp company-pseudo-tooltip-overlay)
              (company-pseudo-tooltip-edit company-selection)))))
```

I haven't been able to understand what all the component parts do.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't have anything to do with the triggering you're curious about...

Comment: I know that it doesn't have to do with triggering it in a custom way. But my question isn't really "how do I make a trigger to do something" - I know how to do that. I want to know how to interact with the frontend for the pseudo tooltip.

Comment: I'm not sure either how the proposed changes are different from customizing `company-idle-delay` or triggering `company-complete` from the `TAB` key.

Comment: I still want to have preview come up quickly/automatically, but not the tooltip.

Comment: For example, my Tab idea would be that I'd like behavior similar to standard completions: press Tab once to complete as far as you can without a choice (and perhaps a single suggestion), then press Tab again to get a tooltip with a list of completions.

Comment: https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/123 seems to cover the same requests.